# Define a vector with random steps

Tags: arrays, matlab, random

I want to create an array that has incremental random steps, I've used this simple code.

```
t_inici=(0:10*rand:100);
```

The problem is that the random number keeps unchangable between steps. Is there any simple way to change the seed of the random number within each step?

Comment: Interesting question, while you attempt shows little understanding. You are creating a linearly spaced vector, with a constant random step size.  What are your limitations? Is there a maximum/minimum step? A maximum/minimum of samples? Already you are limiting your randomness by giving a start and stop fixed value

Comment: here is a generalization for more dimensions... https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/50480-continuous-sampling-in-an-interval--linearly--randomly-and-from-the-simplex

Answer (score 5):

**If you have a set number of points**, say `nPts`, then you could do the following

```
nPts = 10;         % Could use 'randi' here for random number of points
lims = [0, 10]     % Start and end points
x = rand(1, nPts); % Create random numbers  
% Sort and scale x to fit your limits and be ordered 
x = diff(lims) * ( sort(x) - min(x) ) / diff(minmax(x)) + lims(1)
```

This approach always includes your end point, which a `0:dx:10` approach would not necessarily.

---

**If you had some maximum number of points**, say `nPtsMax`, then you could do the following

```
nPtsMax = 1000;      % Max number of points
lims = [0,10];       % Start and end points
% Could do 10* or any other multiplier as in your example in front of 'rand'
x = lims(1) + [0 cumsum(rand(1, nPtsMax))];     
x(x > lims(2)) = []; % remove values above maximum limit
```

This approach may be slower, but is still fairly quick and better represents the behaviour in your question.

Comment: Better than mine, makes sense to shift the random points to the desired corner, instead of adding it.

Comment: Yeah I think that it should make it more random? Just means you can't call it in one line because `x` needs to be used in multiple places, so must be pre-defined. I actually think my updated `cumsum` version is even better, seems to better reflect the desired behaviour...

Answer (score 3):

My first approach to this would be to generate N-2 samples, where N is the desired amount of samples randomly, sort them, and add the extrema:

```
N=50;
endpoint=100;
initpoint=0;
randsamples=sort(rand(1, N-2)*(endpoint-initpoint)+initpoint);
t_inici=[initpoint randsamples endpoint];
```

However not sure how "uniformly random" this is, as you are "faking" the last 2 data, to have the extrema included. This will somehow distort pure randomness (I think). If you are not necessarily interested on including the extrema, then just remove the last line and generate N points. That will make sure that they are indeed random (or as random as MATLAB can create them).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative solution with "uniformly random"

```
[initpoint,endpoint,coef]=deal(0,100,10);
t_inici(1)=initpoint;
while(t_inici(end)<endpoint)
  t_inici(end+1)=t_inici(end)+rand()*coef;
end
t_inici(end)=[];
```

In my point of view, it fits your attempts well with unknown steps, start from 0, but not necessarily end at 100.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't explain well what I needed to acheive but this is what fits better because I don't want to set the number of steps. Thanks to all the other answers too.

Comment: My pleasure, glad that I could help. @Joan

Answer (score 2):

From your code it seems you want a uniformly random step that varies between each two entries. This implies that the number of entries that the vector will have is unknown in advance.

A way to do that is as follows. This is similar to [Hunter Jiang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49434189/define-a-vector-with-random-steps/49434789#49434789) but adds entries in batches instead of one by one, in order to reduce the number of loop iterations.

1. Guess a number of required entries, `n`. Any value will do, but a large value will result in fewer iterations and will probably be more efficient.
2. Initiallize result to the first value.
3. Generate `n` entries and concatenate them to the (temporary) result.
4. See if the current entries are already too many.
5. If they are, cut as needed and output (final) result. Else go back to step 3.

Code:

```
lower_value = 0;
upper_value = 100;
step_scale = 10;
n = 5*(upper_value-lower_value)/step_scale*2; % STEP 1. The number 5 here is arbitrary.
% It's probably more efficient to err with too many than with too few
result = lower_value; % STEP 2
done = false;
while ~done
    result = [result result(end)+cumsum(step_scale*rand(1,n))]; % STEP 3. Include
    % n new entries
    ind_final = find(result>upper_value,1)-1; % STEP 4. Index of first entry exceeding
    % upper_value, if any
    if ind_final % STEP 5. If non-empty, we're done
        result = result(1:ind_final-1);
        done = true;
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this is another interesting answer that could reduce the execution time.